# DocumentDb SQL - Error using ARRAY_CONTAINS in query from DocumentClient

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

I'm attempting to run the following query from an AzureFunction using the DocumentClient:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  c
where
  ARRAY_CONTAINS(
    c.facilities, 
    { \"id\": \"d742df06-5343-44cf-55b5-bce660ccb907\" },
    true
  )
```

(The line breaks were added here for readability)

If I run this query from Query Explorer in Azure Portal, it works perfectly.

If I run this from the Azure Function, I get the following exception:

```
{
  "errors":[
    {
      "severity":"Error",
      "location":{
        "start":22,
        "end":106
      },
      "code":"SC2050",
      "message":"The ARRAY_CONTAINS function requires 2 argument(s)."
    }
  ]
}
```

I personally believe that the fact this is running from Azure Functions is irrelevant - although I haven't had to try it from a locally-running app, I believe I would get the same response because it appears that this error is coming from either DocumentClient or the DocumentDb SQL engine itself.  I do have another Azure CosmosDbTrigger function running in the same project, with the only differences being the collection triggering the function and the query itself - the other one doesn't use ARRAY_CONTAINS().

The query above was copied directly out of the QuerySpec object (from the debugger) I'm passing into following method:

```
dbClient.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(uri, query)
```

I have confirmed that uri has the correct URI to my collection and query contains the query above.  I currently have the ID value from the document that is passed into the Azure Functions trigger replaced with the hard-coded value you see above.

I'm attempting to use the three-argument form of ARRAY_CONTAINS because I only need the ID value to match.

Any ideas why I'm getting this error?

**Update #1**

OK, I decided to open up my handy-dandy copy of LinqPad and write up a little program to test this same code.  I copied and pasted the relevant lines of code from my Azure function into LinqPad and attempted to run it.  This time it worked like a champ.

[image: Dump of query from LinqPad]

So this seems to remove DocumentClient from the equation, at least from the local machine.  Any ideas as to why it would blow up in an Azure Function?

**Update 2**

Here's a slightly edited version of the function code.  To post it here, I've changed the values of some of my static variables in the class.  Other than that, this is the same code that generated the debugger output below.

```
public static class DeleteItem
{
    private static string OtherCollection = "MyOtherCollection";
    private static string MainCollection = "MainCollection";

    [FunctionName("DeleteItem")]
    public static async Task Run(
        [CosmosDBTrigger(
            "myDb",
            "MainCollection",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "DocDbConnectionString"
        )] IReadOnlyList<Document> documents,
        TraceWriter log)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var dbClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri(Config.DocDbEndpoint), Config.DocDbKey))
            {
                foreach (var doc in documents)
                {
                    // Get the ID of the document
                    var itemId = doc.Id;

                    try
                    {
                        // Determine if the doc should be deleted
                        var isDeleted = doc.GetPropertyValue<bool?>("isDeleted");
                        if (!isDeleted.HasValue || !isDeleted.Value) continue;

                        // Query the other collection to see if this item is being used
                        var uri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(Config.DocDbName, OtherCollection);
                        var paramsList = new SqlParameterCollection {
                            new SqlParameter
                            {
                                Name = "@itemId",
                                Value = itemId
                            }
                        };
                        var query = new SqlQuerySpec("SELECT * FROM c where ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.facilities, { id: @itemId }, true)", paramsList);
                        var result = dbClient.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(uri, query).ToList();


                        // If the item wasn't found in the other collection, then go ahead and completely remove it
                        if (!result.Any())
                        {
                            uri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(Config.DocDbName, MainCollection, itemId);
                            await dbClient.DeleteDocumentAsync(uri);
                            log.Info($"Item (Id = {itemId}) has been completely removed from the database.");
                        }

                        // Otherwise just log that we're keeping this as a soft-delete
                        else
                        {
                            log.Info($"Item (Id = {itemId}) stored as soft-delete.");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        log.Error($"Unable to delete item (Id = {itemId})", ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Unable to perform delete operation", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Running in the debugger I see the following before the query executes (unedited):

[image: Screenshot of watch before query execution]

After I run the query, control passes to the catch block where I get the following (unedited):

[image: Screenshot of watch in catch block]

Here are some of the details of that exception (unedited):

```
Exception Message: {"errors":[{"severity":"Error","location":{"start":22,"end":75},"code":"SC2050","message":"The ARRAY_CONTAINS function requires 2 argument(s)."}]}

Inner Exception Message: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A0B00

Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.QueryPartitionProvider.GetPartitionedQueryExecutionInfoInternal(SqlQuerySpec querySpec, PartitionKeyDefinition partitionKeyDefinition, Boolean requireFormattableOrderByQuery, Boolean isContinuationExpected)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DocumentQueryExecutionContextBase.<GetPartitionedQueryExecutionInfoAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DocumentQueryExecutionContextFactory.<CreateDocumentQueryExecutionContextAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQuery`1.<CreateDocumentQueryExecutionContextAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
```

If I take that query and that Id and I dump them into Azure Portal's Query Explorer, I get the following result (Edited by removing ID values and one individual's name):

[image: Query running in Azure Portal Query Explorer]

At this point, I'm getting a little frustrated.  I've tried tweaking that query string, making sure it's not something weird like an extra quote, mismatched quotes, or something else weird like that.  I'm running out of ideas here.

Comment: That definitely seems odd if you're using the DocumentClient directly. What version of DocumentDb are you using in LinqPad? In Functions, we're using 1.13.2 -- can you try that in LinqPad as well?

Comment: I just changed the version of DocumentDb with the version you suggested.  The query still works.  I'm going to update the question with a little more detail from the function, including some screen shots from the debugger.

Comment: Are you running all of this locally in Visual Studio? If so -- what version of `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` do you see in your NuGet refs? At the top of your function, if do `log.Info(typeof(Document).Assembly.Location);`, what does it say? What about `log.Info(typeof(Document).Assembly.FullName);`?

Comment: I get this error when I change my Azure App Service settings from a 32 bit to a 64 bit process. However, I failed to reproduce it in a 64 bit IIS express running on my development machine. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

(5 years later...)
This is reproducible in a console .NET FW project when using any DocumentDb nuget version before 2.11.0 *and running an x64 build*.

(The problem I had was with the `CONTAINS` function, but the error is the same).

Updating the nuget to **2.11** or newer solved the problem.